# Sequence mining with sparse events

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, markov-process, sequence-analysis

I am struggling in finding a good prediction model for the following dataset I have collected. I have sampled a four parameters (say A, B, C, D) which are a normalised values between 0 and 1 among a set of subsequent states $S_t,t=0,n$. This states happen chronologically therefore the order matters.

At the same time each state is associated with a set of events $a_x,x=0,m$ and each association has a integer weight (represented by the thickness of the connection in the picture down below). The number of events is high (they are sparse with a long tail).

The number of states I have sampled is around 1000.

I would like to find a model which given the parameters value in each state, given the weight of each connection with the events allows me to predict the parameter of the current state.

I was thinking one possible solution could be using Hidden Markov Chains but I am not entirely sure how to initialise them.

Any advice how to model this process would be really helpful.

[image: Possible structure of my problem]

Regards,
Daniele